# Python 3 compatible slots

Tags: python-3.x, slots

I am trying to go from `Python2` to `Python3`. So the first step is to program forward compatible. Thus I use the `from __future__` and the `from builtins` imports. However this breaks slots.

While

```
class _Test(object):
    __slots__ = ('a', )

test = _Test()
test.b = 1
```

raises an `AttributeError` as expected

```
from builtins import object

class _Test(object):
    __slots__ = ('a', )

test = _Test()
test.b = 1
```

just runs. Now `test.__dict__` exists. So how can I use slots in `Python3`?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with the new-style class in either 2.7 or 3.6. In both Python versions it produces an `AttributeError` as expected.

Comment: With `python3.5.2` the code properly raises the error. However, `python2.7.12` just runs the code. I don't have any other Python versions to test. I expect only `python2` to fail, as the `from builtins import object` line should do nothing for `python3`.